# Mist Wallet unable to sync due to connection error

Tags: mist, wallets, testnets

Clearly, my internet is working. It didn't have a problem before. Then I got off geth and started using testnet, to which it ceased to sync. Fine.

Then I got back on geth, everything is back to normal, except I get the following error repeatedly with every new chain segment import:

[image]

What can I do to eliminate this and sync my wallet again?

Answer (score 1):

Re-starting the client eliminated the error.